# Apply a strip property to multiple strips

Tags: workflow, video-sequence-editor

Is there a way to apply a strip property (<kbd>n</kbd>) to multiple strips without having to click on each strip individually?

I'm trying to proxy/timecode large number of strips, and it's become very tedious!

Comment: Normally you could right click on the setting and select *Copy to selected*, but for some reason it's not avaible in many places.. You could use a simple python script though.

Comment: I tried **right click on the setting and select Copy to selected** but it didn't work. Any pointers on a possible script would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite simple in python:

```
import bpy

for s in bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences:
    if s.type != 'SOUND':
        s.use_proxy = True
        s.proxy.build_25 = True
        s.proxy.build_50 = False
        s.proxy.build_75 = False
        s.proxy.build_100 = False
```

This will set `use_proxy` to `True` for every strip in the current scene which is not a sound strip.

Just paste it into the text editor (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd>) and press *Run Script* or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>.

Comment: I like the idea of scripting, but when I ran this script it failed and told me to look in the console; from which said **'SoundSequence' object has no attribute 'use_proxy'**. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @reggie My bad, I forgot sounds strips don't have a proxy option. Updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much I love it! This scripting will be so useful!

Comment: Here's a link to the API reference, in case you want to look at it yourself: http://www.blender.org/documentation/250PythonDoc/

Comment: How would I amend this scrip to set the proxy value to 25% for all the strips too? Iv'e been trying for the past hour, but no luck!

Comment: @reggie Updated. You can mouse over any button or option and the python api calls are in the tooltip.

Comment: This gives **:AttributeError: 'MovieSequence' object has no attribute 'build_25'**

Comment: @reggie Oops, stupid mistake.. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Also there is a more complete addon that can perform this task. http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Sequencer/Extra_Sequencer_Actions
There are lots of copy actions in here.